# Styling Previous/Next Pages differently from Index

Tags: pages, archives, css, previous, next

A friend of mine pointed me towards using child elements to style my index page so that I could have one loop and several different visual styles (a featured post, a smaller sub-featured post, and several smaller thumbnails). This is very helpful in that I can add posts and the existing posts will just flow through this styling.

For example, I can style the .hentry class by:

```
.hentry:nth-child(3)
{
background-color:#00000;
}
```

And so on.

The problem I run into is when clicking on the next/previous links on the bottom of the content portion, those following pages maintain that styling.  Is there a way I can style those pages differently?

URL: http://piquantblog.com

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your theme's [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) can be used to target specific pages:

```
body.home /* front and subsequent pages */
body.paged /* any page *except* front page */
```

Comment: What would a specific style using that technique look like?
#body.paged .hentry:nth-child {} ?

Comment: Specific CSS styling is out of scope for WPSE. You should have everything you need to target elements differently, using the CSS classes in @Milo's answer.

Comment: Oh I didn't mean for my website specifically, just what the syntax might look like.  I'm less aware of CSS syntax than I should be!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Milo's answer is the easiest and most elegant solution. However, I do want to highlight a little-known alternative. The [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) includes an almost unknown template file, **`paged.php`**, that only [gets loaded](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L0) if:

1. The current context is paged
2. The current context is an archive
3. None of the archive-tree template files (`archive.php`, `date.php`, `{taxonomy}.php`, `author.php`, etc.) exist

These conditions are almost never all concurrently true; thus, `paged.php` is almost never invoked. But it *is* there, available for use, and would work in the OP's scenario.